# Determine Attributes of an LED

Tags: led, reverse-engineering

I have some devices which have purple LED's in them.  I need to make another one, but don't know anything else about the LED to buy more.

How can I determine the forward voltage and maximum current in order to get similar LEDs?

Comment: You'll probably also want to figure out the spectral distribution (color), intensity, and angular distribution (especially if it's in a non-standard package) if you're going to be replacing some but not all of the LEDs.  Excellent question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like for any other diode forward voltage varies slightly with current:

[image]

You could say it's a constant voltage plus the voltage drop over a resistor.

\$V_F\$ is usually specified at the **nominal current**, which is often 20mA. So place a 100\$\Omega\$ series resistor, and vary the voltage of your bench supply (you've gotta have a bench supply!) until the voltage over the resistor is 2V. The voltage over the LED is \$V_F\$.

You can't measure the **maximum allowed current**. Higher currents will decrease the LED's lifetime, but there's no exact point where you can say that it breaks.
That said, it's no use to go too high. Most common LEDs will not show much increased brightness above 20mA.

Comment: I don't have any of the LED's loose.  They are all integrated into circuits already.  Is there a way to apply your method while keeping them in place?

Comment: @Präriewolf - locate the series resistor of one of the LEDs and determine its resistance value (read the color code). Switch power on and measure voltage over the resistor. Determine current by applying Ohm: \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$. Then measure the voltage over the LED.

Comment: @Präriewolf - just a suggestion: maybe choose a different user name; not everyone will be happy with the Umlaut, keyboard-wise. How about "Praeriewolf"?

Comment: @Steven - [This StackApps script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments) adds reply links to comments, making this easier.

Comment: @stevenvh: Doesn't everyone copy and paste when replying?

Comment: @endolith - Only the lazy ones... alright, I see, so that means everyone :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well for forward voltage you could power it from a voltage supply in series with a very large potentiometer. Slowly decrease the pot while measuring the voltage drop over the pot. Once the voltage becomes somewhat stable then your VCC - Vpot is your Vf.

As for maximum current... get a constant current sinking driver and slowly crank it up until the LED blows? I'm half kidding about that, I'm sure there's a better way.

Comment: You should be able to use a constant current sinking driver to determine the turn-on current, but maximum current is probably better determined by making a conservative estimate from the forward voltage and power capacity of similar packaged devices.